# How to draw and insert a symbol in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I want to make a symbol as shown below in TikZ.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
    \draw[thick] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,1);
    \draw[thick] (0.5,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5);
    \draw[thick] (0.25,0) -- +(0,-0.3);
    \draw[thick] (2.75,0) -- +(0,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to insert it (say **cylinder**) in TikZ codes, like so:

```
\draw[cylinder] (2,2); % this inserts the symbol at point (2,2)
```

Comment: Have you considered making an ordinary macro for this? `\newcommand\cylinder[2]{...}` then `\cylinder{2}{2}`

Comment: It might be worth to define a new shape in this case. Perhaps the [`makeshape`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeshape) will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by John Wickerson, you can write the `\cylinder` macro:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\cylinder[2][]{
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
    \draw[#1] (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
    \draw[#1] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,1);
    \draw[#1] (0.5,0.5) -- (3.5,0.5);
    \draw[#1] (0.25,0) -- +(0,-0.3);
    \draw[#1] (2.75,0) -- +(0,-0.3);
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \cylinder{0,0}
  \cylinder[draw=blue,very thick]{2,2}
  \coordinate (A) at (4,4);
  \cylinder[draw=red,line width=5pt]{A}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]